# Recargar la misma URL con un hash (fragmento) diferente

Tags: javascript, jquery

En la respuesta a una llamada AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
                  'descripcion': descripcion
                },
          url: "<?php echo site_url();?>"+"admin",
          success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data == "1") {
              swal(
                    'Correcto!',
                    'Grupo agregado correctamente!',
                    'success'
                  ).then(function () {
                    $('#add').modal('close');
                    document.location.href = "test#tab1";
                  })
            }else if (data == "2") {
              swal(
                    'Error!',
                    'Ha ocurrido un error, contacte al administrador!',
                    'error'
                  )
            }else if (data == "0") {
              swal(
                    'Error!',
                    'Todos los campos son obligatorios!',
                    'error'
                  )
            }
          }
      });
```

Quiero recargar la página (la misma URL), pero con un `#` (hash o fragmento) diferente. El problema que tengo es en la linea:

```
document.location.href = "test#tab1";
```

Ya que no funciona, es decir no recarga la página en la sección `#tab1`.

Si le quito `#tab1` funciona normal, pero queda en la parte superior de la página y no va a dicho elemento.

**¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El navegador se da cuenta de que es la misma página, por lo que no intenta recargarla, sólo busca el `#tab1` dentro de la página actual.

Para que se refresque, hay que cambiarle el `#tab1` y forzarlo con [`location.reload(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

```
location.hash = 'tab1';
location.reload(true);
```